# Javascript function not working in Wordpress post

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

The following code functions fine on my computer. However, when i paste it into a wordpress post the button shows but doesn't function. What do I need to tweak in Wordpress to get this to work? TIA

```
 <div id="quoteDisplay">
 
 </div>
 <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
 
 
 <script>
 var quotes = [
         'Quote test 1',
         'Quote test 2',
         'Quote test 3',
         'Quote test 4',
         'Quote test 5',
         'Quote test 6',
         'Quote test 7',
         'Quote test 8',
         'Quote test 9',
         'Quote test 10',
         'Quote test 11',
         'Quote test 12',
         'Quote test 13',
         'Quote test 14',
         ]
         





function newQuote() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add  `;` for `quote` variable
2. Try to search for any errors in console